# UITextView set text error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I got an error when I set some text to a `UITextView` but not every string that I set to UITextview gives an error.

The code that returns error:

`NSString *currentDetailText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.activityData.activityDetail]; 
[editActivityPopupView.editTextView setText:currentDetailText];`

EditTextView is the UITextView object.

The error message is:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSBigMutableString characterAtIndex:]: Index 958 out of bounds; string length 957'

I try to set same string to `UITextField` and `UILabel` but it did not give an error.
The string that I use is in Thai Language.
Please give me some advice.

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: You are trying to get substring from string and thats goes to out of bounds.

Comment: This is my code

 NSString *currentDetailText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.activityData.activityDetail];
[editActivityPopupView.editTextView setText:currentDetailText];

editTextView is object that create from UITextView

Comment: I bet this problem only happens with the Thai language and not with English.  What happens when you try `editActivityPopupView.editTextView.text = curentDetailText;`?  Same error?  Also, try adding in a `editActivityPopupView.editTextView.selectable = TRUE;` before setting the text and let me know if that helps.